# Epigraph on Title Page of \part without modifying the epigraph package

Tags: koma-script, book-design, parts, epigraphs

I know there are already some topics on this, but they either don't quite apply or are not working as required, so apologies for opening another thread.

I am using KOMA-script for a book, and I want to be able to include a nice looking epigraph on each "part"-page.

I *cannot*, however, use some easy modification of the epigraph package as is suggested in other threads, as I am using the epigraph for chapters and all changes apply to the whole \epigraph package.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt, 
    a4paper,
    DIV=8, 
    oneside, 
]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\part{Title of Part I}
% Nicely formatted quote to go below the title of the part
\end{document}
```

As always, thank you for all your help :)

Comment: Maybe others know what you have done but I don't. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and what the problem is. You say that you have modified the epigraph code but I have no idea what you have done.

Comment: I have not included the epigraph package in the MWE because I thought it would only distract. My point in the text above was just that I am looking for a solution *without* relying the epigraph package, because I am already using it for the chapters. (Other threads suggest to modify the epigraph package to get the desired results, and I was looking for a way without using epigraph.) Sorry if this was confusing :-)  @cabohah's answer below works brilliantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the KOMA-Script build in commands `\setpartpreamble` and `\dictum` to add *nicely formatted quotes*:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt, 
    a4paper,
    DIV=8, 
    oneside, 
]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\setpartpreamble{%
  \dictum[Sokrates]{The good success is nothing small, 
    but it starts with small things.}%
}
\part{Title of Part I}
% Nicely formatted quote to go below the title of the part
\end{document}
```

There are several commands to change the formatting of the dictum. See section "3.17 Dicta" in [the KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! This works well, and with a bit of \raggeddictum and some \bigskips because vertical alignment is meh etc. it can easily be manipulated. Thank you so much, this solved it very cleanly :)

Answer (score 0):

The manual describes how you can do this. `texdoc epigraph` section 2.5 Epigraphs on Part pages. Perhaps the current package maintainer could consider improving the package, especially if *you*, not me, ask him.